# Three.js uniforms for shading

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

Hi I am trying to do what seems like simple shading with threejs. I am using the Up and Running book by O'reilly.

Everything was working fine, until I tried to do this:

```
                var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["normal"];
            var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

            uniforms["tNormal"].texture = normalMap;
            uniforms["tDiffuse"].texture = surfaceMap;
            uniforms["tSpecular"].texture = specularMap;
```

This keeps throwing this error:

TypeError: uniforms.normal is undefined
[Break On This Error]

uniforms["normal"].texture = normalMap;

I have been looking around online for a while and am not sure what syntax needs to change to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `shader.uniforms` has no "tNormal" attribute. What do you want to do with this shader?

Comment: I was following along with the book. I also the other lines for diffuse and specular,which also throw similar errors.

Answer (score 5):

I think that should be like:

```
uniforms["tNormal"] = {
    texture: normalMap
};
```

Same for `tDiffuse`, `tSpecular`.

Answer (score 2):

I find that when running your code, after the lines:

```
var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["normal"];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);
```

*uniforms* is an object with one member: opacity. Thus *uniforms["tNormal"]* does not yet exist. As Olivia suggested, you could add these in using:

```
uniforms["tNormal"] = {
    texture: normalMap
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error and your code are different. The error reports undefined texture on:

`uniforms["normal"].texture = normalMap;`

The code you cited says you're using:

`uniforms["tNormal"].texture = normalMap;`.

I'm working on the same book examples, try this:

```
var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

uniforms[ "tNormal" ].texture = normalMap;
uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].texture = surfaceMap;
uniforms[ "tSpecular" ].texture = specularMap;

uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;
uniforms[ "enableSpecular" ].value = true;
```